# MySQL find ids when match other table or not exists in it

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables and I want a query to show records from one table that match the second table or doesn't exists at all. In other words if the record exists in table B and does not match the condition don't show it.

```
    TABLE A                TABLE B

    ID  VAL                ID  AID  BVAL
   ---------              ----------------
    1    v1                1    2     B1
    2    v2                2    3     B2
    3    v3
```

I've tried with this query:

```
SELECT ta.id, ta.val, tb.bval 
 FROM table_a ta
 LEFT JOIN table_b tb ON ta.id = tb.AID AND tb.BVAL = 'B1'
```

the goal is to get ONLY this rows:

```
    ID    VAL   BVAL
   ------------------
    1     v1    NULL
    2     v2     B1
```

But obviously with this query I get all Table A.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: But obviously with this query I get all Table A?? You are getting only 2 entries from the query,

Comment: Including mathematical operators in table/column identifiers is a recklessly bad idea.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth the two entries is the result I want to achieve

Comment: Maybe... As and when you provide a comprehensive data set and corresponding result set as per the example I've provided below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a solution, I post it in case someone else is having the same issue.

```
SELECT ta.id, ta.val, tb.bval 
 FROM table_a ta
 LEFT JOIN table_b tb ON ta.id = tb.AID
 GROUP BY ta.id, ta.val, tb.bval
 HAVING tb.BVAL = 'B1' OR tb.BVAL IS NULL
```

Comment: Could you provide a better solution? Less gibberish maybe?